Missing endpoints in FastAPI Swagger UI
I have many endpoints in fastapi app and all works good at localhost, but after deploying service with docker-compose auth endpoint disappears. I think the reason somewhere in deploying, because if i start server without docker endpoint appears.
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - app-network

  backend:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - HOST=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
      - ADMIN_LOGIN=${ADMIN_LOGIN}
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    build: .
    command: sh -c "alembic upgrade head && python3 main.py"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-alpine

COPY . .

RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

I also tried to make post request on auth endpoint(the missing one), thinking it was swagger bug, but got
backend-1   | INFO:     212.45.15.105:26138 - "POST /admin/login HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found`


Docker doesn't do anything with the content of HTTP requests.  If you're getting an HTTP response then the Docker-level wiring is probably correct.  What does the application code look like?  Is there an option that would disable the admin endpoint in some cases?

No, there is no way to disable auth, code:
https://github.com/ilayq/vk_test/blob/main/main.py

i just deleted all docker data (cache, images, etc) and rebuilded. It looks to me docker builded previous version of my app, depending on cache or something

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
